# Power BI Direct Query and created columns with DAX

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbi, dax, directquery

I'm working on a project to ameliorate my skills using power BI

i created 3 tables on Oracle DB (data_2018, market segment and meals) i imported the data on power BI with direct query using this statement :

```
select * from data_2018 
left join  meal on data_2018.meal = meal.meal 
left join client_segment 
on data_2018.market_segment = client_segment.market_segment
```

then i created the following columns on DAX to calculate the income of the hotel

```
total_nights = Query1[STAYS_IN_WEEKEND_NIGHTS] + Query1[STAYS_IN_WEEK_NIGHTS]
room_no_discount = (Query1[DISCOUNT])* Query1[total_nights] *Query1[ADR]
```

1-i can't display the column `room_no_discount` in my visuals and i get the following error
[image]
2-when i try to make visuals using one of the join keys (Meals or Market segment)
i always get this error
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Do the columns that are being referenced exist?  Has the table name changed?  Is the database case sensitive?  Also, this column definition has a repeating string: `room_no_discount = room_no_discount =`

Comment: the columns exist. i used an SQL statement to join the 3 tables (I updated the post to omit the repetition thanks ^^ ) . i tried to import each table separately with direct Query, i created a column 'total_nights = DATA_2018[STAYS_IN_WEEK_NIGHTS] + DATA_2018[STAYS_IN_WEEKEND_NIGHTS] '           but i have this error when i try to make a card visual using the new column : ORA-00904: "t0"."STAYS_IN_WEEKEND_NIGHTS": invalid identifier. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

Comment: Is the source table really named `t0`?  I know this might not fit your goal of learning power bi, but you could just add that calculation to your query.  I lean in favor of doing the work on the source over calculated columns.  Also, is there are need for using direct query rather than importing the data into the model?